# How do I replace "?" with NULL in SSIS expression?

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse

There are ? in my data columns and I have to replace them with NULL. In my SSIS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a question mark is in the column already it must be some kind of string.

Use a derived column and a if function:

```
[colName] == "?" ? NULL(DT_STR, «length», 1252) : [colName]
```

or

```
[colName] == "?" ? NULL(DT_WSTR, «length») : [colName]
```